# Eclipse RCP obtain toolbar contributions programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application and I want disable/enable some elements of the toolbar when I perform some actions. My extension:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
      <toolbar id="vendor.toolbar1h">
         <command commandId="vendor.commands.MyCommand"
          icon="icon.png"
          id="MyButtonID1"
          style="toggle">
         </command>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

I try to enumerate all the toolbar contributions with this code, but it doesn't work, it show only the contributions of the views.

```
IViewReference[] refs = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
   .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
for (IViewReference ref : refs) {
   System.err.println("ID: "+ref.getId());
   IViewPart viewPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
      .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(ref.getId());
   IActionBars bars = viewPart.getViewSite().getActionBars();
   if (bars != null) {
      IToolBarManager tbm = bars.getToolBarManager();
      if (tbm != null) {
         IContributionItem[] items = tbm.getItems();
         for (IContributionItem item : items)
            System.err.println("\t" + item);
         }
      }
}
```

Exists a way to get the main action bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to get access to the main toolbar.  The `IActionBars` toolbar returns the view toolbar (right next to the view tab).

But you enable/disable a command based on the enablement of the active handler.  Your handler is responsible for determining its enabled state.

Programmaticly, if you subclass `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler` you would call `setBaseEnabled(boolean state)` to make sure it fires the correct event.

Declaratively, when contributed via `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` it has support for an `enabledWhen` element as well.  That has access to the application state listed in `org.eclipse.ui.ISources`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your items on the main toolbar, once an IHandler implements the interface IElementUpdater Eclipse’s command framework will use that class to update the label, tooltip, or even images of a command. See this for more details :

http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-label-updating-command-handler/

Comment: unfortunately the link seems broken/outdated
BTW: The question "Is this answer outdated?" should include such an option (broken link)

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the following activity pattern removes the External tools menu contribution. This one was quite difficult to figure out.

```
       <activity id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.unwanted" name="unwanted"/> 

       <activityPatternBinding
       activityId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.unwanted"
       pattern=".*ExternalTool.*">
       </activityPatternBinding>
```