# How do I programmatically find an Eclipse view toolbar control?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I would like to support drag and drop of a file resource onto some plugin view toolbar buttons: this would involve attaching a DropTarget to the underlying Control (a Button). However it is unclear to me how programmatically to retrieve the Button - I can give it a unique id in the plugin.xml but what API calls would I use to then find it? Ideas welcome, thanks!

Update: the code fragment at [Eclipse RCP obtain toolbar contributions programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603405/eclipse-rcp-obtain-toolbar-contributions-programmatically) shows how to navigate to get to the relevant IContributionItem, but then I need the model/widget...

Comment: Your best bet would be to have the view create the Button itself on its actionBars and save the control.  Then whenever you need the droptarget have the view return that control.

Comment: A button is a very unusal drop target. You should consider using a more appropriate _container_ widget instead, e.g. a list or table.